# Is it possible to subset a table by row names that is already a subset?

Tags: r

I had a huge data frame of over 70000 rows which I split into several smaller data frames. These dfs now need to be filtered/split up again and they all still display the continuous row names from the original df, but the row numbers start with 1 for each subset of course.

Original df:

```
structure(list(ID = c("S25", "S25", "S25", "S25", "S25", "S25", 
"S25", "S25", "S25", "S25"), `Step length (km)` = c(0.0199109278453956, 
0.0164543610381346, 0.0132836337125505, 0.0136162564636374, 0.0107277708964608, 
0.0164161750767766, 0.0293870854019551, 0.0124045174064797, 0.0142961706697052, 
0), Angle = c(NA, -2.64417813085975, -1.53209954875884, 2.5154982969622, 
2.38871510555124, -2.29873359207977, 2.54239785024155, 1.69163871104124, 
2.10364018105916, NA), Longitude = c(1.54147, 1.54147, 1.54136, 
1.54152, 1.54133, 1.54143, 1.5412, 1.54154, 1.54162, 1.54142), 
    Latitude = c(50.215488, 50.215309, 50.215439, 50.2155, 50.215511, 
    50.215439, 50.215439, 50.21529, 50.215389, 50.215382), Date = c("07.10.2019", 
    "07.10.2019", "07.10.2019", "07.10.2019", "07.10.2019", "07.10.2019", 
    "07.10.2019", "07.10.2019", "07.10.2019", "07.10.2019"), 
    Time = c("18:01", "18:21", "19:01", "19:21", "19:41", "20:01", 
    "20:21", "21:01", "21:21", "21:41"), Depth = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), land_sea = c("land", "land", "land", "land", 
    "land", "land", "land", "land", "land", "land")), row.names = 69400:69409, class = c("moveData", 
"data.frame"))
```

Code I tried:

```
pv_ID_S25_ft = pv_ID_S25[c('69402':'69407'),]
```

What I get:

```
structure(list(ID = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), `Step length (km)` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Angle = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Longitude = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Latitude = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Date = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    Time = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), Depth = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), land_sea = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c("NA", "NA.1", 
"NA.2", "NA.3", "NA.4"), class = c("moveData", "data.frame"))
```

What I desire:

```
structure(list(ID = c("S25", "S25", "S25", "S25", 
"S25", "S25"), `Step length (km)` = c(0.0132836337125505, 0.0136162564636374, 0.0107277708964608, 
0.0164161750767766, 0.0293870854019551, 0.0124045174064797), Angle = c(-1.53209954875884, 2.5154982969622, 
2.38871510555124, -2.29873359207977, 2.54239785024155, 1.69163871104124), Longitude = c(1.54136, 
1.54152, 1.54133, 1.54143, 1.5412, 1.54154,), 
    Latitude = c(50.215439, 50.2155, 50.215511, 
    50.215439, 50.215439, 50.21529), Date = c("07.10.2019", "07.10.2019", "07.10.2019", "07.10.2019", 
    "07.10.2019", "07.10.2019", ), 
    Time = c("19:01", "19:21", "19:41", "20:01", 
    "20:21", "21:01",), Depth = c(6, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 6), land_sea = c(, "land", "land", 
    "land", "land", "land", "land")), row.names = 69402:69407, class = c("moveData", 
"data.frame"))
```

I already tried different combinations, but I always get a new df1 that just contains NAs all over because R doesn't understand I want to filter by row name not by row number.

All code I found didn't work on my issue.

Comment: Please share a reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Transform the original row name in a column with `tibble::rownames_to_column()` or if you want to preserve the original row number use `tibble::rowid_to_column()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do with base R.

```
pv_ID_S25_ft = pv_ID_S25[rownames(pv_ID_S25) %in% 69402:69407,]
```

**output**

```
        ID Step length (km)     Angle Longitude Latitude       Date  Time Depth
 69402 S25       0.01328363 -1.532100   1.54136 50.21544 07.10.2019 19:01     6
 69403 S25       0.01361626  2.515498   1.54152 50.21550 07.10.2019 19:21     6
 69404 S25       0.01072777  2.388715   1.54133 50.21551 07.10.2019 19:41     6
 69405 S25       0.01641618 -2.298734   1.54143 50.21544 07.10.2019 20:01     6
 69406 S25       0.02938709  2.542398   1.54120 50.21544 07.10.2019 20:21     6
 69407 S25       0.01240452  1.691639   1.54154 50.21529 07.10.2019 21:01     6
       land_sea
 69402     land
 69403     land
 69404     land
 69405     land
 69406     land
 69407     land
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using the `dplyr` and `tibble` packages from the `tidyverse`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

df2 <- df %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "rowid") %>%
  filter(rownames(df) >= 69402 & rownames(df) <= 69407) %>%
  column_to_rownames(var = "rowid")

df2
       ID Step length (km)     Angle Longitude Latitude       Date  Time Depth land_sea
69402 S25       0.01328363 -1.532100   1.54136 50.21544 07.10.2019 19:01     6     land
69403 S25       0.01361626  2.515498   1.54152 50.21550 07.10.2019 19:21     6     land
69404 S25       0.01072777  2.388715   1.54133 50.21551 07.10.2019 19:41     6     land
69405 S25       0.01641618 -2.298734   1.54143 50.21544 07.10.2019 20:01     6     land
69406 S25       0.02938709  2.542398   1.54120 50.21544 07.10.2019 20:21     6     land
69407 S25       0.01240452  1.691639   1.54154 50.21529 07.10.2019 21:01     6     land
```